# Accessing MapReduce configuration/statistics for logging and analysis

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, statistics, reporting

We're working on gathering statistics from our map reduce jobs. We're going to use counters for some things but I wonder if there's some way to access the statistics on the Web UI, such as rows inserted, bytes read/written, etc, in such a way that we can shove them into a database for later inspection.

How does the Web UI gather all this data, and can we use this gathered data in a way that doesn't involve parsing a downloaded html view of the report? Such as a file outputted by the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [tutorial](http://diveintodata.org/2011/03/15/an-example-of-hadoop-mapreduce-counter/) for accessing the job counters. Here is the code to fetch the counters given jobid.

> JobId jobId = new JobId("12345", 0);
>   Cluster cluster = new Cluster(new Configuration());
>
> Job job = cluster.getJob(jobId);
>   Counters counters = job.getCounters();
>
> Counter counter = counters.findCounter(JobCounter.NUM_FAILED_REDUCES);
>   long failedTasks = counter.getValue();

Once the counters have been retrieved put them in a DB and display them in the UI.

Besides the user defined counters [JobCounter](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-0.21/mapreduce/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/JobCounter.java) and [TaskCounter](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-0.21/mapreduce/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/TaskCounter.java) are some of the Hadoop defined counters.

Comment: So, to be clear, the values and stats on the web ui page that shows the results are for the most part stored as built-in counters?